# Change ImageView in different activity dependent on button press

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, imageview

I'm making an application where users can choose a design and then enter their details in the next page. As it stands, the user is given a number of designs to choose from and then, depending on what design they choose, that design will show as a preview in the next page. To avoid having a separate java class for each design, I want to have one class that will change the preview image, depending on what design the user has chosen.

At the moment, I am able to change the image displayed on the second activity, but cannot change the image to the specific design chosen by the user.

[This is what the page looks like where the user chooses their design (named SelectDesign.java)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arjNP.jpg)

[This is what the preview page looks like (named GarmentEntry.java)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj4iY.png)

Here's the code for the activity where they choose the design - SelectDesign.java (I've only included the first three designs for simplicity's sake - they all have the same basic outline)

```
package com.example.joe.printedclothing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SelectDesign extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Button HenCockButton, CocktailHenButton, ValueHenButton, XAngelsButton, AlcDisposal, LastNightOfFreedom, BeaverPatrol, Paraletic, FellasOnTour, ValueStag, Wolfpack, PhotoStagHen;
ImageView imagePreviewButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_design);

    HenCockButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hencocksthumbB);
    HenCockButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent henCockIntent = new Intent(SelectDesign.this, GarmentEntry.class);
            henCockIntent.putExtra("hen cock parameter", R.drawable.onehenthreechicks);
            startActivity(henCockIntent);
        }
    });

    CocktailHenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cocktailhenthumb);
    CocktailHenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cocktailHenIntent = new Intent(SelectDesign.this, GarmentEntry.class);
            cocktailHenIntent.putExtra("cocktail hen parameter", R.drawable.cocktailhen);
            startActivity(cocktailHenIntent);
        }
    });

    ValueHenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valuehenthumb);
    ValueHenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent valueHenIntent = new Intent(SelectDesign.this, GarmentEntry.class);
            valueHenIntent.putExtra("Value Hen parameter", R.drawable.valuehen);
            startActivity(valueHenIntent);

        }
    });
```

Here's the code for the activity where they enter their details and there is a preview - GarmentEntry.java (excluding the code for things like spinners and buttons)

```
package com.example.joe.printedclothing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class GarmentEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner tcshenspinner, backprintoptionsspinner, tcbackhenspinner, cosspinner, ppspinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> tcshenspinneradapter, backprintoptionsspinneradapter, tcbackhenspinneradapter, cosspinneradapter, ppspinneradapter;
Button nextButton1;
public static ImageView imagePreview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.garment_entry);

    imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);
    // Hen cocks
    imagePreview.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("hen cock parameter", R.drawable.onehenthreechicks));
    // Cocktail hen
    imagePreview.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("cocktail hen parameter", R.drawable.cocktailhen));
    // Value hen
    imagePreview.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("Value Hen parameter", R.drawable.valuehen));
```

Right now, I understand that the reason why only one image is being passed into the next activity. The code is being read sequentially and so it takes the last value that it reads (I think I'm correct here). But I have no idea how to make the image change dependent on which image the user selects. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your first problem is that you are providing the default value as the actual resource ID in the function getIntExtra(). This means that If the Intent is queried for the feild "Value hen parameter" and finds it empty, it will still return the default value. Aside from that I think your approach in using the Intent extra is right, but you are using it wrong.

A better idea would be to set one key for the Intent, who's value will be the image you would like to display in the second activity. for example

```
public static final String IMAGE_RES_ID = "image_res_id";
private Intent intent = new Intent(SelectDesign.this, GarmentEntry.class);
   ....
   ....
   ....
   CocktailHenButton.setOnClick(
       ....
       intent.putExtra(IMAGE_RES_ID, R.drawable.cocktailhen);
       startActivity(intent);
   }

   ValueHenButon.setOnClick(
        ....
        intent.putExtra(IMAGE_RES_ID, R.drawable.valuehen);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and then in the GarmetEntry.class, use a single statement to populate the image:

```
    imagePreview.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra(SelectDesign.IMAGE_RES_ID, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define one key for the image resource extra, such as:

```
public static final String RESOURCE_EXTRA = "resource_extra";
```

Use it to pass your resource extra to the intent for starting activity:

```
henCockIntent.putExtra(RESOURCE_EXTRA, R.drawable.onehenthreechicks);
```

And in the second activity, retrieve the resource id with this key:

```
imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePreview);

imagePreview.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra(RESOURCE_EXTRA, R.drawable.valuehen)); // of course the default drawable id could be different
```

The thing you did wrong was using different keys for the one extra you wish to pass to the next activity. There's one imageView you need to changethe drawable of, so use one extra key, retrieve always with the same key, just put different things with this key in the first activity.